# Remove focus from cell in datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus, lost-focus

i have simple datagrid

```
    MySqlCommand cmd = m.getmodel(stmt);
    MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable data = new DataTable(equip);
    dataAdapter.Fill(data);
    var checkBoxColumn = new DataColumn("Select", typeof(bool));
    data.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn);

    checkBoxColumn.SetOrdinal(0); // Move column to the beginning
    foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
    {
        row["Select"] = false;

    }
    //to make all data uneditable except first
    foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
    {
        if (col.ColumnName == "Select")
            col.ReadOnly = false;
        else
            col.ReadOnly = true;
    }
    data2.ItemsSource = data.DefaultView;
    checkBoxColumn.ReadOnly = false;
    data.RowChanged += ChangeEvent_RowChanged_wh;
```

and here is my change event

```
    void ChangeEvent_RowChanged_wh(object sender, System.Data.DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {   
        //wh is a global arraylist
        var imei = e.Row["imei"];
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row["Select"]))
        {

            wh.Add(imei);
        }
        else
        {
            wh.Remove(imei);
        }

        int cr_c = wh.Count;
        wh_cr_bd.Badge = cr_c;
        lose_focus();
    }
```

now look here in that picture

[image]

this badge on down is associated with number of selections as mentioned above

now it showing that i have checked only 3 but in reality i checked only 2 , i fix it by clicking outside he program but this not effecient especially for the consumers , anyone have any idea that i can lose focus from all datagrid without clicking outside ? i have tried :

```
    datagrid.Focus();

    datagrid.UnselectAll();
```

but no hope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Keyboard.ClearFocus method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.clearfocus?view=netframework-4.8). Just keep in mind that if you use `Bindings` with `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`, it may not update them. (This however doesn't seem to be your case)

If it doesn't work, there is also more advanced class [FocusManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.focusmanager?view=netframework-4.8). `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement` allows you to set focus to any other focusable element. It actually behaves like clicking outside.

Comment: Hello , thanks for help . Unfortuantly i tried both of them . No result

Comment: What element did you set focus to? You may have to set it outside the DataGrid. I think settings focus on any parent of the DataGrid wouldn't work either.

Create a StackPanel and put your DataGrid and a TextBox in it. Then set focus to the textbox.